# Comment promoted to answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette

I run into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013408/set-variable-with-function#20013462) with rather simple solution which was placed as the first comment by SuperScript user.

Two minutes after this, another user literally copied this single sentence comment into answer with no added value. Since he is 113k rank and later other users commented with more useful notes, it seems to me like automated and rather parasitic behavior.

I've met situations like this before, but at least the answer added something useful. So what to do with situations like this? Is it desirable/honest to hijack the comment?

Comment: I see this happening all the time in the tags I participate in. Often times my comment is the one copied, as I don't feel it was enough of an answer.. You do have to note that it may not necessarily be copied, as sometimes there is actually only one answer.

Comment: In that specific instance, it's the only "reasonable" answer I can think of - it may not have been copied.

Comment: Doesn't mean that only superscript knows the answer. I mean a guy with more than 100k rep will not look greedy for more points.. right? (I hope so).

Comment: I'm often too lazy to write a full answer and only post a minimalistic answer as comment. if somebody takes that comment and build a full answer from it, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The person making the comment should have posted an answer instead. If they chose not to do so, and someone else did, I don't see a problem.

It happens to me all the time; I'll post a comment that seems to be the simple solution, and someone else will take that and make it an answer. It's my fault, not theirs, because I decided to post the comment instead.

In regards to the specific question you linked, there is no "literal copy" with "no added value" IMO. There's a difference between "Maybe this?" and a paragraph with an actual code sample. The first is a question ("Maybe this will work?") and is a possible hint; the second is an answer with an example, and took time to write.

Comment: Still, it seems to me that encouraging the comentator to transform his comment into answer would be more honest, especially from such high ranked user. I can accept it, but I don't like it.

Comment: That might be a nice thing to do, and I've often posted a comment to a comment saying "Joe, you should make that an answer instead" (and had others say the same to me - @Shog9 just recently did that to a comment I made here to a post that's since been deleted), but it's still my responsibility to post an answer in order to get the rep. If I choose not to do so, that's nobody's fault but my own. :)

Comment: Indeed. We want to discourage folks from posting answers as comments (as it happens far too often), and the risk of having someone else post the answer for them is one of the ways we do so.

Comment: Also, you don't want to drag the whole process of answering for too long. If you ask the person who commented, it may be a while before they come back to post an answer.

Comment: Also sometimes they can flat out refuse ("I posted it as a comment and not an answer for a reason", whatever that reason may be).

Answer (score 3):

IMO, in this case, most of the users who viewed that post knows the answer. They may be just not fast as "SuperScript" commented on the post. Now it doesn't mean that "SuperScript" holds the authority to post the comment as answer later when other users manage to make him to do so.

In simple words, if you know the answer, just post it as answer. (*if it has not already been answered as a **answer***).