# How to deal with not-so-useful answers posted as comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've run into a problem several times where I post a question and someone responds an incomplete or not-useful answer as a comment.

Engaging in conversation by responding to the comment ends up polluting the question with useless comments. When I've tried asking posters to migrate their comment to an answer, quite often they say they'll do it "later" and never do (e.g. [Is it possible to virtualize a LAN?](https://superuser.com/q/681900/57662))

How do we deal with this "netiquette" problem? I would love to be able to downvote/hide comments but [Allow downvoting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/142724) indicates this RFE was declined.

I am expecting comments on questions to ask for clarification about the question itself. Anything else should go into an answer.

Comment: What if I don't feel like fleshing out a full-blown answer, but still have information that is likely to help the OP? What if I have "try this" suggestions that don't warrant an answer? I do agree that posting answers as comments sucks a bit - not for the reason you mention though, but because it might inhibit others from posting an answer that says the same as the comment. But apart from that - why would you want to hide something that is useful to future generations?

Comment: @probablyPekka What makes you believe "try this" couldn't be posted as an answer

Comment: The fact that it's based on a hunch and I don't know whether it's going to work. That said - what you did on your question is perfectly reasonable, isn't it? Remind the user to post a full answer as they promised.

Comment: @probablyPekka translation: you want to post possible answers without risking your reputation. Sorry, but that's just lazy :) No one (at least not me) will fault you for a bad hunch... Yes, I can certainly remind users to migrate to an answer but very often I find that they do not actually do so.

Comment: I couldn't care less about reputation. I care about posting answers that are actually worthwhile. Posting hunches through comments is perfectly reasonable. As said, I do think the practice of posting an answer as a comment *and leaving it at that* is slightly unfair to other users, but not for the reasons you state.

Comment: @probablyPekka Okay, so I guess that's subjective. I view all answers as worthwhile. Worse-case scenario you can delete them and all related noise goes away at once. Look at the alternative. If the answer you were posting now turned out to be wrong, we'd be left with 6+ useless comments pointing to the wrong solution with no way to make them go away. Fact is: StackExchange does a much better job of suppressing bad answers than bad comments.

Comment: *"Try this `<code block>`"* answers are really really really really bad IMO. Often you have to play "spot the difference" to actually find the changes and these answers are just not educating. They don't explain what the actual problem was, they don't explain why the code in the answer solves the problem.

Comment: @Gilli That's a fair point, I don't disagree with that. But - in your example, would you have preferred for Zoredache not to post anything at all - taking away any possibility to communicate with him, ever? This site is based on people donating slices of their time. If I don't have enough time (or inclination) to provide a good answer, but I'm willing to post a comment, is it really beneficial not to do so?

Comment: @probablyPekka I would have loved for him to post exactly what he did, but as an answer. I don't know why people think that answers must be elaborate. All they need to do is point you in the right direction. Someone else then comes along and improves on that answer, and so on, until we end up with an accepted answer.

Comment: *"I don't know why people think that answers must be elaborate."* Because we want quality?

Comment: There's a much higher standard expected from answers. Remember - the questions and answers on Stack Overflow are not only for *you*, they are supposed to build an archive of knowledge for future generations. The contributions need to have some form of coherence for that. That's why many of us feel inclined to post either a good answer, or none at all... it's perfectly fair to ask a commenter to make a complete answer out of their comment, though.

Comment: "Try this" isn't an **answer**. It's a suggestion of something to try. It has nothing to do with "risking downvotes"; it has to do with this site *not* being about reputation, wild speculation, and guesswork, and actually being about collecting knowledge. I agree with @probablyPekka here. All answers are not worthwhile, or we wouldn't have the ability to flag them or downvote them (or delete them when the downvote count gets excessive). I flag "answers" often that say "try this" with an external link; that's not an "answer", and is not "worthwhile".

Answer (score 8):

It's sometimes messy, but people will occasionally post answers as comments - because they have no time to post an answer, they are too lazy to do so (like me!), or because they don't trust their suggestion will work.

Overall, the practice's benefits (that valuable information is posted, which might otherwise not be posted) arguably outweigh its downsides.

If you see such a thing, and the comment is the perfect answer to the question, you can suggest to the commenter that they provide a full answer. There are many good reasons to do that, for example the fact that comments are second-class citizens and may get deleted by moderators, or perhaps you have follow-up questions.

If they do not turn their comment into an answer, and it's your question, it is perfectly within your rights to use the commenter's input and self-answer your question with the solution.

It is also always perfectly legitimate for *any* user on the site to take the commenter's information, and turn it into an answer. (Of course, you need to make sure that it's a complete, good, and correct answer.) Of course, it's polite (and technically, even required) to credit the commenter in the answer.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207638/172661) seems relevant.

Comment: My question wasn't regarding comments that should be promoted to accepted answers, rather comments that are either invalid answers or answers that require further clarification. In short, I can't act on the comment and I am being forced to start an entire conversation in the question discussion thread (versus linking the discussion to a specific answer).

Comment: @Gili I see your point, but is not having the information there at all really the better alternative?